# Error creating Web Service Client in Netbeans

Tags: java, wcf, iis, netbeans, azure

I am trying to consume a WCF service deployed in Windows Azure from a Java Applet. When I create new Web Service Client in Netbeans, I got an error when processing "http://10.61.132.143/?xsd=xsd0":

> Se ha devuelto una excepción de E/S al procesar
>   "http://10.61.132.143/?xsd=xsd0". Excepción:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect.

I think 10.61.132.143 IP cannot accessed beacause it is a **private IP** generated by Azure load balancer.

This is the [WSDL definition](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/639494/wsdl.xml).

Any idea of how to solve it?

Comment: *"I got an error"*  What error?  BTW - I would advise dropping one of the lesser tags for [tag:java].

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is a ConnectException error when processing that address. I have uploaded a screenshot.

Comment: Copy/paste the text rather than post a screen-shot!  It is less bytes and more searchable.